# I want to get value is selected in ChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I wrote forms.py like

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django import forms

class InputForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
  select1 = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,required=False)
  select2 = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,required=False)
```

in html

```
<div>
    {{ f.select1 }}
     <label　for="select1" dataGoTo="7">select１</label>
    {{ f.select2 }}
     <label for="select2">select２</label>
</div>
```

in views.py

```
def get_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InputForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
```

I want to get value which select1 or select2 is selected.
How should I write in views.py?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this in Javascript using Ajax. Right click the page in your browser and select 'view source'. Figure out what are your form's and select element's id or class. Then in your Javascript (jQuery) right the following:

```
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form#form_id').on('submit', function(){
  // your option elements must have a 'value' attribute
  var selectedValue = $('select#select_id').val();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'your/view/url',
    data:{
        'selected': selectedValue,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data){
        // error handling
        if (data['status']==='ok') {
            // display success message
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }, // success
  }); //ajax
}); // on form submit
}); // document ready
```

Then in your views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import JsonResponse


class SomeAjaxView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            selected = request.POST.get('selected', None)

            if selected:
                # do something here

                return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'status':'ko', 'error': 'Value missing'})

        return JsonResponse({'status':'ko', 'error': 'Not authenticated'})
```

Using Ajax has the benefit of not refreshing the entire page on submit. This is the industry-standard practice nowadays.